# Last value in pointer memory is incorrect

Tags: c, pointers, loops, fwrite

The program is long(here is the full version: http://pastebin.com/cvg1eSJ1), (sample.txt looks like this: http://pastebin.com/hWihPpSj, it is the INPUT file, and another command line argument is the output file.) but I am posting the parts dealing with the 'second pointer list'. Essentially I have a list of 47 or so items, and I need to add items outside of a certain range to a second list. This is where I first save the values. I use "tempAddress" just to clean up the code some. I just take the value at the current address, check it, and if it matches then add it to the second Reading List.

```
    for (i; i < numElements; i++) {
        tempAddress = firstReadingList++;
        if ((double) *tempAddress > plusOutlier || (double) *tempAddress < minusOutlier) {
            *secondReadingList++ = *tempAddress;

            numOutliers++;
            printf("%d ", *tempAddress);
        }
    }
```

Later on, I have to write this reading list in another function to a file. I print out the values, and ONLY the last value is incorrect. I have no idea why. Here is the code where I write them to the file(tempAddress is a new variable in this case)

```
for (i; i < numElements; i++) {
    tempAddress = (outlierList + i);
    printf("%d ", *tempAddress);
    fprintf(out, "%d ", *tempAddress);
}
```

The output in the first function is as follows:

752 843 840 848 752 850 753 (this is correct)

The second code snippit outputs this

752 843 840 848 752 850 577 (577 is incorrect)

Did I do something wrong? I'm still relatively new to pointers. I DO NOT modify the secondListPointer at any point between functions.

Comment: *"The program is long, but I am posting the relevant parts."* - How do you know which parts are relevant if you don't understand what the error is?

Comment: I mean this is the only part where the second pointer list is referenced at all. The rest of the program just deals with initializing the first list, of which the data is correct(average, standard deviation, etc)

Comment: I don't even know what you mean by *pointer list* so I can't help you at all. Also, *second pointer list*? What's the first one?

Comment: The first pointer list is initialized like so: 
 
'int *memoryAt;
        int size = 47;
 for (i; i < size; i++) {
  memoryAt = (data + i);
  fscanf(in, "%d", memoryAt);
 }'


I mean it works fine, so (data + i) is the current memory address, and *memoryAt is the value at that address. So I established that there are 47 elements, so it loops through and adds data from the address at 'data' to the address at 'data + 46'. I read my values that way. Then for the second pointer list, which is just allocated memory, I set the values at the address of the first reading lists to the second's.

Comment: Why are you paraphrasing your code instead of just showing us the code? Your "explanation" explains nothing because it doesn't tell us the values of `i`, `data`, and `in`. (Also, you're not handling errors in `fscanf`.)

Comment: You need to show the declaration and initialization of firstReadingList, secondReadingList and outlierList.

Comment: Okay, here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/cvg1eSJ1

I'll also update the main post with this

Comment: This `for (i; i < numElements; i++) {` looks quite wrong. Either you should initialise `i` in the for-loop header, or not mention it at all before the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you call `get_outliers`, you allocate memory for **one** `int`:

```
int *outlierList = malloc(sizeof *outlierList);

int numOutliers = get_outliers(dataPointer, numReadings, outlierList, average, stdDev, STDDEV_SCALAR);
```

but there may be more than one outlier. Then you write outside the allocated memory, invoking undefined behaviour, with unforeseeable consequences. Here, just some data was corrupted.

Comment: So should I use calloc with size being the number of outliers? I wouldn't have the number of outliers before that point.

Comment: `malloc` or `calloc` isn't so important, but you must allocate enough space for all outliers. The safe option is to `malloc(numReadings*sizeof *outlierList);` (if `numReadings` is in fact the total number of elements), but you could also allocate less (how many you expect plus a bit leeway). And you need to keep track of the number of outliers, and if the allocated space is filled, react.

Comment: WOW that totally fixed it. Thank you so much. I didn't realize it was corrupted because I figured something like corrupted data would look like messed up text or something, or give an error. That fixed it perfectly.

Comment: Well, that's the insidious part of undefined behaviour, it doesn't always show, and when it shows, you can't always recognise the cause. If you have only few outliers, it is likely to work as if it were correct, since `malloc` only hands out aligned memory, so when you ask for memory for one `int`, the chunk that `malloc` marks as handed out to you is usually larger - maybe large enough for four `int`s, maybe more, maybe less. As long as you remain in that block, nothing shows. Step outside it, and something overwrites something else's memory.

Comment: Very helpful for a beginner. Thank you Daniel